# Angular 400 error PUT when editing only one field

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

**I have 2 input fields, when I edit only one input and submit I get 400 Error PUT, but when I edit both inputs its allright.** 
PICTURE OF THE ERROR: https://ibb.co/cbw1QPS 
Service component:

```
  //PUT
    updateBank(data: Ext, id: number) {
        return this.http.put<Ext>('/someData/' + id, data).pipe(
            map(res => {
                return res;
            })
        );
    }
```

Component Ts

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
 this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      code: [''],
      name: [''],
    });
  }

  //Get by id
  byId() {
    this.itemService.getItemById(this.id).subscribe((res) => {
      return (this.singleS = res);
    });
  }

 //Update
  update() {
    this.singleS.code = this.myForm .value.code;
    this.singleS.name = this.myForm .value.name;
    
    this.banksService
      .updateBank(this.singleS, this.singleS.id)
      .subscribe({
        next: (res: any) => {

        this.showMessage('Updated');
      }, error: (errorMessage) => {
        this.showMessage(errorMessage.errorMessage);
      }});
  }
```

**Component HTML, In my component html I have to get the details from the byId() function and passed in the value section in the html. It updates but only when I edit both inputs, I want to edit only one and when I submit it edits only the one I edited and the other stays the same.**

```
<form [formGroup]="bankForm">
      <label for="code">Code</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        id="code"
        formControlName="code"
        [value]="singleS?.code"
      />
      <label for="name">name</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        id="name"
        formControlName="name"
        [value]="singleS?.name"
      />
 <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="update()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: HTTP 400 indicates a `Bad Request` meaning the syntax of your request isn't accepted by the backend. You could use your dev tools to look at both requests and see what they look like. And then take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually setting any values to your form... so if you do not edit the values in the input, you are sending an empty string. Do **NOT** use `[value]` when you are using a reactive form, instead you should set the value in the **form** (formcontrols) instead.

So when you get the initial values from the backend, you can use `patchValue` to set the values to the form:

```
byId() {
  this.itemService.getItemById(this.id).subscribe((res) => {
    this.singleS = res;
    this.myForm.patchValue(res);
  });
}
```

And in the template, remove `value`:

```
  <input
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    id="code"
    formControlName="code"
  />
  <label for="name">name</label>
  <input
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    id="name"
    formControlName="name"
  />
```

And your submit:

```
update() {
  this.singleS.code = this.myForm.value.code;
  this.singleS.name = this.myForm.value.name;
  this.banksService.updateBank(this.singleS, this.singleS.id)
    //....
}
```

Comment: I need singleS because I'm fetching data from the backend directly.
And in the api singleS has an id, name and code.
The id ngOnInit(){} is the id from the route

Comment: OK, then use `singleS` instead :)